# How can I use AddHandler AddressOf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a web app using Visual Studio VB.NET. I have a web form with two panels. I have the code below:

```
Protected Sub WebForm2_load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim y As Integer = 1
    Protected cr(100) As Button 

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()
    End If
    con.Open()
    Dim requ As String
    requ = "SELECT DISTINCT ENSEIGNEMENTS.Code_Mat From ENSEIGNANT INNER Join ENSEIGNEMENTS On ENSEIGNANT.Code_Ens = ENSEIGNEMENTS.Code_Ens where NomUser='" + un + "' and Sem='S1'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(requ, con)
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While rd.Read()
        cr(y) = New Button
        cr(y).Text = rd("Code_Mat").ToString
        cr(y).ID = "btn" & y.ToString
        Panel1.Controls.Add(cr(y))
        AddHandler cr(y).Click, AddressOf btnc
        y = y + 1
    End While 
End Sub

Protected Sub btnc(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Protected cr1(100) As Button 
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()
    End If
    con.Open()
    Dim btn As Button()
    Dim x As Integer = 1

    Dim requete As String
    cdmat = CType(sender, Button).Text
    'Response.Redirect("TestGroupes.aspx")
    requete = "SELECT ENSEIGNEMENTS.Gr FROM ENSEIGNANT INNER JOIN ENSEIGNEMENTS ON ENSEIGNANT.Code_Ens = ENSEIGNEMENTS.Code_Ens WHERE (((ENSEIGNEMENTS.Code_Mat)='" + cdmat + "') AND ((ENSEIGNANT.[NomUser])='" + un + "') AND ((ENSEIGNEMENTS.[Sem])='S1'))"
    Dim commande As New SqlCommand
    commande = New SqlCommand(requete, con)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = commande.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        cr1(x) = New Button()
        cr1(x).Text = reader("Gr").ToString
        cr1(x).ID = "bt" & x.ToString
        Panel2.Controls.Add(cr1(x))
        AddHandler cr1(x).Click, AddressOf Groupe
        x = x + 1
    End While
End Sub

Protected Sub Groupe(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox("hhhhh")
End Sub
```

My problem is that `AddHandler cr(y).Click, AdressOf btnc` and `WenForm2_load` work well but `AddHandler cr1(x).Click, AdressOf Groupe` does not: when I click on a button in Panel2 nothing happens.

Comment: If the web server is not on the same computer as the browser, you won't see the MsgBox because that appears on the computer running the code, i.e. the web server.

Comment: It is on the same computer , I'm working on the localhost

Comment: OK. Perhaps something is preventing the web server from creating a MsgBox that you can see. Instead, you could add a control like an `asp:Literal` to the page somewhere it will be visible and set its .Text to "hhhhh".

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work ...watever I put in Sub Groupe nothing happens

Comment: `Me.Load` does work because it can successfully hookup the `click` event to `btnc`. The issue is inside this event of `btnc`, it is also trying to create a dynamic event handler, `AddHandler cr1(x).Click, AddressOf Groupe`, which will *not work* because it **has to be done on the page load/init** and also outside the `!IsPostBack`...

Comment: Did you reference System.Windows.Forms where MessageBox lives? Why not try Debug.Print for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always create the primary buttons (Code_Mat), but you also need to re-create the secondary buttons (Gr) when it posts back, so you'll need to save the variable(s) used to create those secondary buttons.

As a demonstration, I created a new Web Forms project named "testing" with one page named "index.aspx":

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="index.aspx.vb" Inherits="testing.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        </div>
        <asp:Literal id="msg" runat="server">msg</asp:Literal>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this code-behind:

```
Public Class index
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Sub Groupe(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim bn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        msg.Text = bn.CommandArgument

    End Sub

    Sub CreateSecondaryButtonsHelper(codeMat As String)
        Panel2.Controls.Clear()
        For i = 1 To 3
            Dim bn As New Button With {.Text = "Gr" & i & codeMat, .ID = "bnB" & i, .CommandArgument = "Hello from " & codeMat & i}
            AddHandler bn.Click, AddressOf Groupe
            Panel2.Controls.Add(bn)
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub CreateSecondaryButtons(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim clickedButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        CreateSecondaryButtonsHelper(clickedButton.Text)

        Session("CodeMat") = clickedButton.Text

    End Sub

    Sub CreateMainButtons()
        For i = 1 To 3
            Dim bn As New Button With {.Text = "CodeMat" & i, .ID = "bnA" & i}
            AddHandler bn.Click, AddressOf CreateSecondaryButtons
            Panel1.Controls.Add(bn)
        Next

        If Session("CodeMat") IsNot Nothing Then
            CreateSecondaryButtonsHelper(CStr(Session("CodeMat")))
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        CreateMainButtons()

    End Sub

End Class
```

It is rather dull, but I think it shows what you want to do.

---

N.B. You should make a new SqlConnection each time you use it and call .Dispose() on it as soon as you've finished using it. Also, using SQL parameters to pass the values instead of making up a string with them will make it more reliable and avoid SQL injection attacks.